# Detecting vertical page overflow using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to conditionally render something a div judging by whether the browser window has a vertical scroll bar. My `renderElements` method pulls from an API and the results vary. I've tried assigning a ref to my div and comparing it's scrollHeight to it's innerHeight in `ComponentDidUpdate`. Despite cases where the page does have a scrollbar due to multiple results coming in, my `hasOverflow` variable always returns `false`. What would be the most ideal way to get this to work?

```
class ExampleClass extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const element = this.element;

    const hasOverflow = element.scrollHeight > element.innerHeight;

    console.log(hasOverflow);
  }

  render() {
    <div ref={ el => { this.element = el } }>
      { this.renderElemnts() }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: `This didn't work` What exactly didn't work? Is the `element.scrollHeight` wrong?

Comment: Hey. Revised my post for clarity. Basically, despite cases where the page does have a scrollbar due to multiple results coming in, my `hasOverflow` variable always returns `false`

Comment: You have to check it in a onResize listener on the window, not on componentDidUpdate

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Even if I'm not physically resizing the window?

Comment: If resizing window does not change your UI heights you can avoid it

Comment: I don't think I understand you 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHeight` is a function of the window so `element.innerHeight` is always `undefined`, therefore `element.scrollHeight > element.innerHeight` is always `false`.

What is you're looking for `element.offsetHeight`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vb4quk

If you want to test if the window have scroll, you can check with

```
document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-afjlmr?file=index.js

Comment: So retrospectively I think I'm looking to see if the entire page itself has scrolling. The container of elements would cause the "stretching" per se.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment. Is the requirement changed? What are you looking for?

Comment: I think I just worded my original question wrong. In short, I just wanna see if the window has vertical scrollbar at any given moment.

Comment: With the post you provided, do I have access to the body in React the same way I would in jQuery?

Comment: I don't see why not. If something is not working for you, let me know..

Comment: `window` has no `scrollHeight` property. Use `innerHeight` instead. (I updated the answer accordantly)

Comment: Great. Thank you.